# Jquery each loop creating a json output

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have bin working on this for hours now.

In php I would have done this

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($input as $obj) {
   $array[$i]['subject'] = $obj;
   $i++;
}
$json = json_encode($array);
```

In Jquery i have this, where I have multiple form inputs with the same name, and I need to create a json input to submit safely in the form.

```
var i = 0;
$('.tekstforms').each(function(i, obj) {
   items[i]['emne'] = $(this).closest(".tekstforms").find("[name='emne']").val(); 
   i++;                                                             
});
alert(JSON.stringify(items));
```

But that's not working

Comment: what is the length of $(this).closest(".tekstforms").find("[name='emne']") ?

Comment: `items[i]['emne]` typo with missing `'`?

Comment: It comes from a on submit even, so this I covered. I can get the string output from alert og console log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this snippet:

You can take the attribute `[name="emne"]` as selector: `$('.form-of-emne [name="emne"]').each()`

```js
var items = {};
$('.form-of-emne [name="emne"]').each(function(i) {
   items[i] = {
    ['emne']: $(this).val()
   }                                                         
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(items));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-of-emne">
  <input type="text" name="emne" value="abc">
  <input type="text" name="emne" value="xyz">
  <input type="text" name="emne" value="123">
</form>
```

Comment: I have more input fields that has to be grouped

I will edit original

Comment: You can list them `$('[name="emne"], [name="emne2"]')`.